# What am I really missing with Lubuntu compared to the regular Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, battery, ram, lxde

I was reading this article comparing different flavors of Ubuntu: https://itsfoss.com/which-ubuntu-install/
It seems that Lubuntu is extremely lightweight with very low RAM requirements which fits perfectly to my needs. I wanna install Lubuntu to a laptop that would be used for browsing and office work. So, power efficiency is important which to my understanding, Lubuntu would be better in this regard compared to other distributions.
However, I also read in the ubuntu wiki that

*The differences between Lubuntu and Ubuntu are:
Different DE - Lubuntu uses LXDE while Ubuntu uses Unity as the default DE on releases up to Lubuntu 18.04 LTS. Lubuntu uses LXQt from Lubuntu 18.10.
Different Default Applications
Other than that, they are the same. The DE is what makes Lubuntu a lightweight OS, and of course the selected applications too because we make sure to use the lightest applications which are not resource hungry. However, you are still free to use any application available in Ubuntu’s repositories, as long as your computer can run it.*

So, if I can run all the applications of normal Ubuntu on Lubuntu, what am I  missing with the lighter desktop environment? If the LXDE provides the same benefits as Unity does but using much lower RAM, why use unity at all?
I don't really care about default programs since I can install whatever I happen to need at will.

Comment: Don't compare against Unity. Unity is as far as I know discontinued (unfortunately). In the recent years the default Ubuntu comes with Gnome desktop.

Comment: Besides "lightweightness", the choosing of a DE is a matter of preferences. Everybody has a different workflow, and some DE would suit they better that other. I didn't like gnome at first, now it is my DE of choice, no matter what distro I use. Be aware of the DE's fanboys, don't listen to them :)

Comment: My bad, I wanted to say GNOME as I realize that is the default DE for Ubuntu. So, the way I see it, there is nothing except potential aesthetic differences to justify GNOME over LXDE? On a desktop where battery life is of no concern, I can see one installing whichever flavor one prefers, but what could possibly justify 8 times more RAM usage of GNOME over LXDE if the targeted device is a laptop?

Comment: I think it's possible to have both desktops installed on the same system, and then the login screen will offer a select widget before logging in, where one can pick which DE to launch for the session. That way you could evaluate both. Then you can even come back, and add an answer to your own question ;)

Comment: [Here's some data about gnome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_Window_System_desktop_environments#Comparison_of_ease_of_use_and_stability).

Comment: I haven't used a Lubuntu later than 18.04 and the new one is significantly different. In the old versions, the biggest difference from a user perspective was that Lubuntu didn't have the nice 'settings' page with all the settings in one place. You had to hunt through a bunch of different apps to find settings. That said, I still preferred Lubuntu.

Comment: Thanks Levente, I am aware of dual booting. And I did watch youtube reviews of both Lubuntu and regular Ubuntu. I must say I didn't see much difference except visual stuff. 
So, in short, can I say that as far as practical capabilities are concerned, Lubuntu offers the same stuff while requiring 8 times less RAM?
This is my main concern, just to make sure that there isn't something important that is missing at the cost of being light on the system.

Comment: Lubuntu post 18.04 isn't really 'lightweight' like it once was. It uses LXQt instead of LXDE. But, as to what you're missing, the answer is 'nothing'. You can install anything on Lubuntu that you'd install on Ubuntu, including the DE - though doing so would be rather redundant. You're free to add and remove almost all the software you want. Technically you can remove all the software you want, but you may end up with an inoperable system.

Comment: I see, I have two questions though.
1) On the article that I linked it said that lubuntu works perfectly fine on 512 MB of RAM and the article was updated on late 2020. If LXQt isn't as lightweight as LXDE, should I use the latest LXDE version of lubuntu if I care about battery life?
Can I "upgrade" from different flavors of ubuntu to others or would I have to reinstall?

Comment: No need to "upgrade" from one flavor to another: you can "install" the additional desktop environments on your system at any point, and let them exist in parallel. With that said, I would do that only for a temporary evaluation period. I don't have much experience with this, but for this purpose I would probably go with the default Gnome Ubuntu, and would try to install LXDE / LXQT, and XFCE on top, and would just test-drive each. Having arrived at an idea which one I prefer, I would nuke the OS and replace it with a clean new install with the Ubuntu flavor dedicated to that desktop.

Comment: By letting them exist in parallel, are you referring to dual-booting?
My hypothetical was if I decided that I don't like GNOME Ubuntu which I already installed, can I switch/upgrade to Lubuntu or some other flavor of ubuntu or would I have to do a clean install, assign partitions, lose settings, etc?

Also, I think I don't understand the difference between different Ubuntu flavors. I know GNOME Ubuntu needs 4GB of RAM at least while Lubuntu would do fine with less than 1GB: Is the only difference between those 2 just the DE? So, installing LXQT on "regular" Ubuntu turns it into Lubuntu?

Comment: @EvilRaceHorse - *"are you referring to dual-booting"* - no, you can install all DEs you want in your OS, and switch at login.

Comment: LXDE is now compiled in GTK3 version and works good.
more information can be found at unofficial GIT repo!
https://github.com/lxde-gtk3

Answer (score 4):

Both of the 'heavyweight' Ubuntu desktops (Gnome and KDE) provide code and components that are then shared by both the desktop itself and many applications in the same 'family'. For example, the 'file open' dialogue that is used to open files in any program. At a more advanced level, each provides its own password manager (Gnome Keychain and KWallet respectively). LXDE only provides the bare minimum of such components.

If you install any application from the respective family (such as Gnome's Gedit text editor or KDE's Kate text editor) you will have to install the basic components for that family. And you may need to install more components to get the application's full feature set. Many of these components need to run continuously and so will add to your system's minimum RAM requirement. And now you have two sets of such components: the original LXDE ones and the Gnome/KDE ones you have added. You are possibly using more RAM than if you had just installed the 'heavyweight' DE.

If you just want to use a PC for browsing, you could choose a browser that is not part of either family (e.g. Firefox) and in that case Lubuntu is a good choice for you. But Firefox should (in theory, I don't know about in practice) use more RAM than Konqueror because it has to provide all its own code and components. Whether KDE-including-Konqueror uses more RAM than Lubuntu+Firefox is something that you could calculate.

If someone needed to edit images for their office work, they might decide the only adequate Linux application was Glimpse, which is part of the Gnome 'family' (GTK). In that case, they might as well install Gnome anyway and re-use the components for Gedit and other GTK-family programmes.

Comment: That's a very useful thing to point out.

Comment: To have a glimpse into what would happen, try `sudo apt install kate --dry-run`. Kate is a KDE application. You will see a MOUNTAIN of dependencies that would get installed (if it was not a simulated dry-run). Performing such a check (with `--dry-run` or just `-s`) before installing anything new, can easily prevent accidentally ending up with this mountain of dependencies. But then again, I can imagine it's just a matter of time until one cannot resist installing some app with the huge dependencies, because one simply cannot live without that app...

Comment: Thank you for the insightful reply. I am aware that Lubuntu provides less default applications. But for example if I wanted the password manager that comes with regular Ubuntu, can I manually install that to Lubuntu later if I want to?
I mean, it doesn't seem much of a concern to me if I can add the missing stuff at will if I feel like I may need them.

Comment: @EvilRaceHorse while you can add (almost?) any software, the spirit of this answer suggests that you might want to always pick the lighter-weight applications for any purpose. I think there might be such a consequence that you have to choose between installing something heavy-wieight (but that would invalidate your efforts on a light system), or, having to choose command-line-interface programs (potentially) without a graphical user interface. That would mean you would **end up doing more tasks inside terminal windows** as opposed to clicking around in easier-to-use graphical windows.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't install anything heavyweight  unless it is inevitable. However, I really doubt that will be the case since I will be using it only for basic tasks (browsing, office programs, etc.) I mean, if I sacrifice some visual quality for a lot longer battery life, so be it.

Answer (score 4):

Mostly this is just @Matthew's answer in different wording (I'm late to this question sorry).

> So, if I can run all the applications of normal Ubuntu on Lubuntu, what am I missing with the lighter desktop environment? If the LXDE provides the same benefits as Unity does but using much lower RAM, why use unity at all?

**toolkits or resources used (especially ram)**

LXDE was very light, but it was also GTK2  (ie. older GNOME+GIMP toolkit or libraries).  Unity 7 used GTK3, as GNOME 3 has for a ~decade now..

The moment you started using GTK3 apps on the GTK2 LXDE environment, the *lightness* of LXDE was starting to erode, as you ended up with GTK2 libs in memory (needed for desktop), plus GTK3 libs in memory (needed for your applications).  That is one problem with LXDE (or XFCE when it used used GTK2.. you didn't provide release details; Xubuntu/XFCE is GTK3 from Xubuntu 19.10 onwards).  *Same applied back with Ubuntu-MATE/MATE only it ported much earlier; I used to love MATE on a pentium M laptop with 1GB of ram, dropped it when it ported to GTK3*.

**security**

Next is GTK2 is dead upstream, no longer getting security patches, as were done only until `gimp` (last GTK2 program) completed it's port to GTK3. So there are now potentially security risks with GTK2 as flaws aren't being patched.  (new work is being performed on GTK4, GTK3 is where legacy maintenance now occurs)

**LXDE -> LXQt history & toolkits, esp. related to Lubuntu**

PCman (*developer* of `pcmanfm` which was LXDE's file manager, but also handles the desktop itself) started porting it to GTK3 years ago, but there was a huge performance hit (GTK3 is heavier), so the work was paused, then a new port was done to Qt5. The Qt5 port was far lighter & had better performance...  (*PCman has blogged about this, it was long ago now*)

The LXDE devs joined with Razor-Qt guys & are now the LXQt team. That's why Lubuntu switched from LXDE (depreciated except with 18.04) to LXQt.  LXQt uses Qt5 libraries.

Lubuntu is I believe the lightest out-of-the-box of the Ubuntu *flavors* (be it LXDE using GTK2 or LXQt using Qt5), however if you're intended to use GTK3 apps, the advantage will quickly be lost, and it may not be best for you.

**applications to be used**

Consider the applications you'll use in your decision of what desktop.  What toolkit do they use? as ideally you want it to be ones already in RAM, as they're used by the desktop itself thus resource *hit* will be less.

In particular attention pay attention to apps you'll use at the same time, eg. I still use Liferea (GTK3), Hexchat (GTK2) & Evolution (GTK3 MUA) on my LXQt system, the resource *hit* is greatest when I load the first of them, but *hit* isn't there for 2nd & 3rd app as libs are already in memory. My old 2009 desktop can cope because it has enough ram; so I can keep using apps I used back when GNOME2 was my desktop.

**taste**

Further, there is taste. Not all of us think "*chocolate*" is the best ice-cream, so different desktops allow us to work in a particular way that suits us, so beyond the *lightness* or *toolkits* in use, we can choose one that meets our *tastes*, or weigh *lightness* against the other things we value (in our *kepner-tregoe* selection spreadsheets)

FYI:  *I used boxes with 1GB of ram to test releases up to and including Lubuntu & Xubuntu 19.04.   I still do (*18.04.5 was last in 2020-August*), however most of my testing now involves boxes with more RAM.  The amount of RAM you have will dictate how much care you take, with 2GB or less I'd plan ahead, with >4GB of RAM I tend to ignore it & use the applications I want to.  The desktop I'm replying to you on, is a 2009 dell so it's *old* (c2q-9400) and my base is Lubuntu/LXQt, but I still use GTK3 apps I started using when GNOME was GNOME2 (& thus GTK2) as with 8GB I can afford the RAM hit.  When using less ram devices though I'm much more careful*.

Comment: FYI:   I don't consider I'm missing anything running Lubuntu.  Actually my system also has `ubuntu-desktop`, and `xubuntu-desktop` installed, so I can logout, and choose to use `GNOME` or `XFCE` as my desktop... but boxes either side of me are almost identical (just have `lubuntu-desktop` & `kubuntu-desktop` installed though I spend 50% of my time using boxes with only `lubuntu-desktop` installed..  I can run all GTK3 apps on any Lubuntu.. they just use slightly more RAM, just as using a Qt5 app on a GTK3 desktop does...  "six vs half-dozen"...

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. My main hope with installing Lubuntu is that I expect to get better battery life compared to regular Ubuntu. I used to get somehow worse battery life on normal ubuntu compared to Windows 10. So, I expect Lubuntu to be less draining than windows 10.
In short, taste goes out of the window for me if there is a significant drain on the battery and if Lubuntu has essentially the same functionality as GNOME Ubuntu, then I see no reason why Lubuntu does't win this.

Comment: I can't speak to battery life sorry; I prefer desktops so that's what I use. I QA-test on laptops, but battery life isn't part of the current QA tests (I'm not OEM testing). I count resources as RAM (no impact to battery) & cycles (that would but not significantly; though motors use power so do reduced cpu-cycles dropped enough to not cause fan to start? I don't know). There are questions on this site for `tlp` and power management but it's not in my skillset sorry.

Comment: No problem, thanks again for your response.

Comment: This answer provides a lot of the detail and history behind my 'ELI5' answer.